# Filtro de cadastros por data

Tags: php, mysql

Meu código não está funcionando o que pode estar errado?
No banco de dados a **data** está com Data/Horário como **`datetime`**, segue o código:

```
<?php       
    $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM c_clientes WHERE cliente_data_cadastro 
               BETWEEN '2018-04-07 12:53:14' AND '2018-05-07 12:53:14'");

    echo "<center>". mysqli_num_rows($query). " Registros</center>";

    while($row = $query->fetch_array())
    {       
        echo $row['cliente_data_cadastro']." - "
             .$row['cliente_nome']." "
             .$row['cliente_sobrenome']."<br>"; 

    }       
?>
```

Comment: Mas o que não esta funcionando? E qual é o objetivo do código?

Comment: Filtrar os cadastros dentro de 1 mês! Não carrega nada

Comment: Minha pergunta é óbvia, mas você já conferiu se realmente há registros existentes dentro desta faixa de datas?

Comment: Sim tenho cerca de 300 registros por dia! Fora que fiz testes com DB apenas com datas para teste!

Comment: Experimente `SELECT * FROM c_clientes WHERE ( cliente_data_cadastro 
               BETWEEN '2018-04-07 12:53:14' AND '2018-05-07 12:53:14')`

Comment: Se o tipo de coluna é DATETIME, que armazena valores de datas e horário no formato YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss, porque retirando as horas funcionou? Eu rodei seu código em uma tabela do meu banco e rodou direitinho. A real solução não me parece passar pela retirada das horas! Algum equivoco da sua parte no banco com relação a coluna das datas. Veja esse resultado  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTUfU.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se não tem necessidade de comparar as horas, use a função `TRUNC`:

```
<?php       
    $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM c_clientes WHERE trunc(cliente_data_cadastro) 
               BETWEEN '2018-04-07' AND '2018-05-07'");

    echo "<center>". mysqli_num_rows($query). " Registros</center>";

    while($row = $query->fetch_array())
    {       
        echo $row['cliente_data_cadastro']." - "
             .$row['cliente_nome']." "
             .$row['cliente_sobrenome']."<br>"; 

    }       
?>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, continua não aparecendo nada!

Comment: como está o formato da data no banco? ANO-MES-DIA ?

Comment: Banco de dados: cliente_data_cadastro datetime. http://prntscr.com/jeulpj

Comment: Alterei a resposta, sem a hora. Tenta agora.

Comment: Funcionou! Mas tirei o trunc!

Comment: Ok! Se tua intenção não é saber a hora exata, passa só a data. Mas se for receber uma variavel para essa consulta deixa o trunc, é mais garantido que vá passar a data sem horas.

Comment: Veja a edição que fiz, passei o trunc para o campo do where.

Comment: Se o tipo de coluna é DATETIME, que armazena valores de datas e horário no formato `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`,  porque retirar as horas?

Comment: Veja esse resultado https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTUfU.png